# Why are post offices always a target for robbers in anime?

Tags: culture

I've seen quite a number of anime where the targets for robbers are mostly post offices and not banks and or other places that could have money. Is this a plot device that started somewhere or is it actually a fact that robbers actually go for post offices in Japan? If it is the latter, can someone shed some light on why post offices are a favourite target for robbers?

Some examples of anime that have post offices robbed off the top of my head are Sword Art Online and Toaru Majutsu no Index. There are probably more titles where this happens that I can't remember.

Comment: In real life, robbers tend to favor gas stations, groceries, or ATMs. Bank robberies tend to happen in (Hollywood) movies mostly. The thing is, gas stations, groceries, or even jewelries can be robbed with little to no equipment. To rob a bank you'd need not only a highly specialized and experienced crew, but also all sorts of tools that aren't easy to come by.

Comment: @Nolonar It is not difficult to rob a bank. If you walk into a bank and slip a teller a note saying "I have a gun. Give me all the money you have.", the teller will likely comply, even if you don't actually brandish a gun. The hard part is getting away with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Japan's post offices *are* banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Post_Bank). And the Japanese postal banking system is nothing to sneeze at. In fact, in 2008, Japan Post Bank held [more deposits than any other bank in the *whole world*](http://www.bloomberg.com/apps/news?pid=newsarchive&sid=aeorvTng.HAA)!

It is hence unsurprising that shows set in Japan, like *Index* and *Sword Art Online*, might feature robberies on post offices. There's a lot of money to be had there!